# Change Default Beamer slide size

Tags: r-markdown, beamer

In R markdown when using Beamer slides if you try to plot you need to specify the plot sizes (unlike in the reports) so that the plots fit on a page. This can often result in the plots appearing to be squashed together, as apposed to just a smaller version of the plot. 
Is there some method to change the default slide size to alleviate this problem?

I have tried

```
header-includes: 
    - \usepackage[papersize={25.6cm,19.2cm}]{geometry}
```

in the yaml header, and I get the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

Using R Markdown I shouldn't need to use this though.

A reproducible example is shown below

````
---
title: "Plots look bad"
author: "Beavis"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d/%m/%Y')`"
output: beamer_presentation
header-includes: 
   - \usepackage{float}
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(results = 'hide')
knitr::opts_chunk$set(warning = FALSE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache=TRUE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.height=3.5)
```

# Introduction


```{r}
pca <- prcomp(iris[,1:4])
biplot(pca)
```
````

Here, you if you run this the second slide looks like this [image: tin] As you can see the plot is rubbish. What is the best way to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `biplot` function uses `par(pty = "s")` to force a square plot, so it's not going to fill a rectangular slide.  You can make it look better by asking the `fig.height` to be bigger, but then it will overflow the bottom of the slide.  To prevent this, you can set both `fig.height` to a large number, and `out.height` (which will be a LaTeX measurement) to something that will fit on a slide.  For example, using this chunk

````
```{r fig.height=10, out.height="0.8\\textheight"}
pca <- prcomp(iris[,1:4])
biplot(pca)
```
````

I see this output:

[image: screenshot]

I'd recommend a smaller `fig.height`, but your preference may be different.

Both `fig.height` and `out.height` could be specified using `knitr::opts_chunk$set` as defaults for all slides if you want.

You could also specify `out.width="\\textwidth"` for a really ugly stretched plot that fills the slide, but I wouldn't recommend it.